# replace classes from sun.security.* packages

Tags: java, security, java-8, java-7

I'm trying to upgrade an app from JDK7 to JDK8 which uses the following classes from the `sun.security.*` packages

```
sun.security.x509.X509CertImpl
sun.security.pkcs11.SunPKCS11
sun.security.util.DerOutputStream
sun.security.util.DerValue
sun.security.util.ObjectIdentifier
sun.security.pkcs.PKCS10
sun.security.x509.X500Name
sun.security.pkcs11.SunPKCS11
sun.security.pkcs11.wrapper.CK_TOKEN_INFO
sun.security.pkcs.PKCS10
```

The usage of these classes generates warnings in all cases except for `sun.security.pkcs.PKCS10` which causes a compilation error, because this class no longer exists. It seems that it has moved to a different package `sun.security.pkcs10.PKCS10`.

While I could simply changes this package name and ignore the warnings generated by the other `sun.security` classes, I understand that [you're not supposed to use classes in `sun.security` packages](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/faq-sun-packages-142232.html). How do I go about replacing these classes with their equivalent from the JDK8 public API?

Comment: How did you address this ? How did you go about finding similar classes in Bouncy Castle ?

Answer (score 10):

There aren't any equivalents in the JDK8 public API.  You should switch to the [BouncyCastle API](http://www.bouncycastle.org/) instead.