# Android ssh connection JSch

Tags: java, android, ssh, jsch

I try to open ssh connection via JSch. I added com.jcraft.jsch and com.jcraft.jzlib package in my src folder. But when I try to run my application I had an error org.ietf.jgss package. That package I successfully found and added but at this moment I have a problem with package sun.security.jgss.spi and package sun.security.util

As I found packet sun.security is no available more. Thats correct? 
I must use another library for ssh connection?

Comment: I use this library and I dont have any problem

Comment: /Users/AndrijSenyk/AndroidStudioProjects/Ustat/app/src/main/java/org/ietf/jgss/GSSContext.java     Error:(28, 1) error: package sun.security.jgss.spi does not exist

Comment: I use jdk1.7.0_75 and jdk1.8.0_31.jdk problem is same

Comment: I think I had similar problem like in this post http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28603005/replace-classes-from-sun-security-packages/28603120#28603120

Comment: I use Java version 6, I don't know if this could be the cause

Comment: I Install Java 6 but I have another error - Error:(3, 22) compileSdkVersion android-21 requires compiling with JDK 7
Download JDK 7 Select a JDK from the File System Open build.gradle File      any idea how to run JSch in Java 7 or 8?

Comment: Do you use Eclipse or Android Studio?

Comment: Android Studio, but I solved my problem I used ganymed