# IntelliJ says the package does not exist, But I can access the package

Tags: java, intellij-idea, playframework, sbt

I get the error below, but I can find the package in rt.jar.
I can see the JDK being used from Project Structure.
I'm not sure what's missing.

```
Error:(6, -1) Play 2 Compiler: 
 C:\user\projects\portal\app\com\example\security\cert\X509Cert.java:6: package sun.security.pkcs10 does not exist
 import sun.security.pkcs10.*;
 C:\user\projects\portal\app\com\v\security\cert\GenerateCSR.java:75: cannot find symbol
```

Comment: http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/faq-sun-packages-142232.html

Comment: @rc thanks, great link, i kind of knew that, compiler issues warnings, if i use these imports, But why do I get the does not exist error?

Comment: this might help http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28603005/replace-classes-from-sun-security-packages

Comment: @nullpointer there is the requirement not to use BC. But the main thing here is Intellij and why it does not find a package that's in the rt.jar

Comment: @Spiff yes, if possible, I think you should

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is not an intellij issue.

You need to compile with the `-XDignore.symbol.file` option. Some internal packages
are hidden by default unless you add this option to javac.

https://bugs.openjdk.java.net/browse/JDK-7141442

[sun.security.x509.CertAndKeyGen and sun.security.pkcs.PKCS10 - missing in JDK8. Implementation suggestions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29060064/sun-security-x509-certandkeygen-and-sun-security-pkcs-pkcs10-missing-in-jdk8)

Also the comment of user @user180100 is relevant and important.

> The sun.* packages are not part of the supported, public interface.
>   A
>   Java program that directly calls into sun.* packages is not guaranteed
>   to work on all Java-compatible platforms. In fact, such a program is
>   not guaranteed to work even in future versions on the same platform.

Comment: _You need to compile with the -XDignore.symbol.file option_. Where in IntelliJ IDEA I can specify this option?

Comment: It should be File->Settings->Build Execution Deployment->Java Compiler-> Additional command line parameters

Comment: Nope. It doesn't help. I created bug report https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-241594

Comment: @turbanoff: Eugene Zhuravlev's comment in the linked issue finally explains the exact reasons why those error messages occur.

Answer (score 37):

I had similar issue with different package:
`package sun.security.x509 does not exist`

I used java 11 to compile the project.

In my case I had to disable `Use '--release' option for cross-compilation` in Java Compiler settings.[image]

Comment: This did work for me, I haven't have any secondary effects yet. With this option, IntelliJ deduces from project settings when the cross-compilation is needed and automatically applies the --release compiler option for Java 9. according to this answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/49618223/7032513

Comment: I didn't analyse this option too much. It worked for me so I was happy. What do you mean "cross-compilation"?

Comment: By default, classes are compiled against the bootstrap of the platform that javac shipped with (The low code that the JVM needs to run). But javac also supports cross-compiling, where classes are compiled against a bootstraps of a different Java platform implementation. I think my project wouldn't even be able to compile if this would be an issue so I think this solution is fine.

Comment: This did not work for me.

Answer (score 4):

I had a similar error for a different package.

The packages we use were mapped to a network drive and my credentials to access that mapped drive were expired, so I had re-authenticate and tried with

IntelliJ: File -> Invalidate caches / Restart

OR

```
$gradle clean build
```

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 4):

Your project SDK version under file>project structure>Project>Project SDK must be the same with your java compiler project bytecode version under file>Build, Execution, Deployment>Compiler>Java Compiler> look for "project bytecode version" right under your checkbox for "use '--release....'"

1.Project SDK version:
[image]

2.Project Bytecode version
[image]

Answer (score 0):

Click on the project and chose Maven->Reload This can solve it as well if deps our out sync

Answer (score 0):

My computer abruptly gave a blue screen while I was writing code. On going back to the IDE, I got this exception [Java Minidumps are not enabled by default on client versions of Windows](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61865938/java-minidumps-are-not-enabled-by-default-on-client-versions-of-windows) which I resolved by updating/re-installing JDK.

After resolving the above error, this dependency was no longer visible. I noticed that my IDE was now pointing to the newly updated JDK.

I updated the project's JDK version by going to > File > Project Structure > Project: From here, I selected JDK 1.8.0_65.

Please refer to the screenshot for more clarity.
[image]