# What is the “Use '--release' option” in IntelliJ 2018.1 preferences?

Tags: java, intellij-idea, compilation, javac, java-9

In the preferences for IntelliJ 2018.1 (Build, Execution, Deployment > Compiler > Java Compiler) is an checkbox labeled:

> Use '--release' option for cross-compilation (Java 9 and later)

I found for information when doing an internet search. The "?" help icon give a 404 error when clicked.

What is the purpose/function of this option?

[image]

Comment: This Q/A is as well suited for other IDE's such as Eclipse and of course - since it is an official compiler option - for the JDK (just adding some keywords for search engines here).

Answer (score 14, accepted):

The help section [can be found here](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/java-compiler.html):

> By default, this option is selected. IntelliJ IDEA deduces from
>   project settings when the cross-compilation is needed and
>   automatically applies the --release compiler option for Java 9.

What is the `--release` option? It is a new command-line option, defined in [*JEP 247: Compile for Older Platform Versions*](http://openjdk.java.net/jeps/247).

> A new command-line option, `--release`, is defined, which automatically configures the compiler to produce class files that will link against an implementation of the given platform version.

Discussed in this [good answer here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/43103038/104891).

Also check [IDEA-184333](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-184333) for the background why this option was added in the IDE. In short, some users need to specify only `-source` and `-target` versions for their projects without also setting the `-bootclasspath` option.