# Fatal error compiling: release version 10.0.1 not supported using IntelliJ IDEA and Maven

Tags: java, maven, intellij-idea, junit

On macOS Catalina 10.15.4, I have jdk-10.0.1 installed.

When I go to the Terminal and type in:

```
echo $JAVA_HOME
```

stdout:

```
/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk-10.0.1.jdk/Contents/Home
```

---

Java version:

```
java -version
java version "10.0.1" 2018-04-17
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment 18.3 (build 10.0.1+10)
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM 18.3 (build 10.0.1+10, mixed mode)
```

---

```
mvn -version
```

```
mvn -version
Apache Maven 3.6.3 (cecedd343002696d0abb50b32b541b8a6ba2883f)
Maven home: /Users/pnwlover/maven/apache-maven-3.6.3
Java version: 10.0.1, vendor: Oracle Corporation, runtime: /Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk-10.0.1.jdk/Contents/Home
Default locale: en_US, platform encoding: UTF-8
OS name: "mac os x", version: "10.15.4", arch: "x86_64", family: "mac"
```

---

Created a sample maven project and set JUnit 5 as a dependency:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <groupId>com.sample</groupId>
    <artifactId>Calculator</artifactId>
    <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>

    <properties>
        <java.version>10.0.1</java.version>
        <maven.compiler.source>10.0.1</maven.compiler.source>
        <maven.compiler.target>10.0.1</maven.compiler.target>
        <junit-jupiter.version>5.3.2</junit-jupiter.version>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
    </properties>

    <dependencies>
        <!-- junit 5 -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.junit.jupiter</groupId>
            <artifactId>junit-jupiter-engine</artifactId>
            <version>${junit-jupiter.version}</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>

    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.8.0</version>
                <configuration>
                    <release>10.0.1</release>
                </configuration>
                <dependencies>
                    <dependency>
                        <groupId>org.ow2.asm</groupId>
                        <artifactId>asm</artifactId>
                        <version>6.2</version> 
                    </dependency>
                </dependencies>
            </plugin>

            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.22.0</version>
                <dependencies>
                    <dependency>
                        <groupId>org.ow2.asm</groupId>
                        <artifactId>asm</artifactId>
                        <version>6.1.1</version>
                    </dependency>
                </dependencies>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>

</project>
```

---

Calculator class:

```
package com.sample;

public class Calculator {

    public static int add(int a, int b) {
        return a + b;
    }
}
```

---

JUnit 5 test:

```
package com.sample;

import org.junit.jupiter.api.Test;

import static org.junit.jupiter.api.Assertions.assertEquals;

public class CalculatorTest {

    @Test
    public void add() {
        assertEquals(5, Calculator.add(2, 2));
    }

}
```

---

When I run it via Terminal or IntelliJ IDEA Ultimate Edition 2019.3 (as a Maven run config `mvn test`), I get the following error:

```
[INFO] Scanning for projects...
[INFO] 
[INFO] ---------------------< com.sample:Calculator >----------------------
[INFO] Building Calculator 1.0-SNAPSHOT
[INFO] --------------------------------[ jar ]---------------------------------
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- maven-resources-plugin:2.6:resources (default-resources) @ Calculator ---
[INFO] Using 'UTF-8' encoding to copy filtered resources.
[INFO] Copying 0 resource
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- maven-compiler-plugin:3.8.0:compile (default-compile) @ Calculator ---
[INFO] Changes detected - recompiling the module!
[INFO] Compiling 2 source files to /Users/pnwlover/Calculator/target/classes
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] BUILD FAILURE
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Total time:  0.655 s
[INFO] Finished at: 2020-04-04T16:57:35-07:00
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-compiler-plugin:3.8.0:compile (default-compile) on project Calculator: Fatal error compiling: release version 10.0.1 not supported -> [Help 1]
[ERROR] 
[ERROR] To see the full stack trace of the errors, re-run Maven with the -e switch.
[ERROR] Re-run Maven using the -X switch to enable full debug logging.
[ERROR] 
[ERROR] For more information about the errors and possible solutions, please read the following articles:
[ERROR] [Help 1] http://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/MAVEN/MojoExecutionException
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Java source/target version specified as `10.0.1` is not supported. You should use the major version only like `10` instead:

```
<java.version>10</java.version>
<maven.compiler.source>10</maven.compiler.source>
<maven.compiler.target>10</maven.compiler.target>
```

```
<configuration>
    <release>10</release>
</configuration>
```

In IntelliJ IDEA open `pom.xml` file, press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>R</kbd> (<kbd>Alt</kbd>/<kbd>Option</kbd>+<kbd>R</kbd> on macOS) for **Replace** action, type `10.0.1` in the search field, <kbd>Tab</kbd>, type `10` in the replace field, <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>A</kbd> for **Replace All**.

Comment: Thanks @CrazyCoder - this worked! How did you put those buttons in your answer?

Comment: @PacificNW_Lover `<kbd>` tag, I use this extension: https://stackapps.com/questions/3341/kbd-superscript-and-subscript-markup-shortcuts.

Comment: thanks but Google Chrome won't let me install it... How do you use / install this JavaScript file with Stack Overflow?

Comment: Tampermonkey: https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/tampermonkey/dhdgffkkebhmkfjojejmpbldmpobfkfo

Comment: CrazyCoder - Installed it via TamperMonkey and when I create a new question, I can see that widget but the ```<kbd>hello</kbd>``` doesn't work inline inside the comments text field.

Comment: Note that it will not work in comments, only in questions and answers.

Comment: With JDK9+ you should use `maven.compiler.release` instead of `source/target`..

Comment: @khmarbaise it depends on your goals, in some cases using `--release` [may be not what the user wants](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49618223/104891).