# Java Minidumps are not enabled by default on client versions of Windows

Tags: java

I'm trying to compile and run my java code but when i start it, I get the error:

```
#
# A fatal error has been detected by the Java Runtime Environment:
#
#  EXCEPTION_ACCESS_VIOLATION (0xc0000005) at pc=0x00007ffad5344013, pid=9444, tid=16196
#
# JRE version: OpenJDK Runtime Environment (11.0.5+10) (build 11.0.5+10-b520.30)
# Java VM: OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM (11.0.5+10-b520.30, mixed mode, sharing, tiered, compressed oops, g1 gc, windows-amd64)
# Problematic frame:
# C  [nvoglv64.dll+0x6c4013]
#
# No core dump will be written. Minidumps are not enabled by default on client versions of Windows
#
# An error report file with more information is saved as:
# D:\java\game\hs_err_pid9444.log
#
# If you would like to submit a bug report, please visit:
#   http://bugreport.java.com/bugreport/crash.jsp
# The crash happened outside the Java Virtual Machine in native code.
# See problematic frame for where to report the bug.
#

Process finished with exit code 1
```

I'm using IntelliJ Idea and it's my first encounter to this error.

Comment: Check out this answer, it may help you: https://stackoverflow.com/a/19958230/4949750

Comment: Error is still showing

Comment: You should probably check the file listed in error message: `D:\java\game\hs_err_pid9444.log` - it might contain some useful information on how to solve it.

Comment: Well i still don't know how to fix it because i'm pretty new to java